# Clustering of dissimilar matrix with NA values for heatmap without imputation

Tags: r, heatmap, hclust

I am trying to make a heatmap of a dissimilar matrix that a lot of NAs. However, I ran into problems when trying to perform clustering. Without clustering the heatmap works fine. I do not want to impute/remove the NAs. Is there anyway to perform clustering?
I understand that with NAs calculating distance is a problem but there should be a way around it, right?

I get the following error message:

" Error in hclust(get_dist(submat, distance), method = method) :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)

In addition: Warning message:
NA exists in the matrix, calculating distance by removing NA values."

Edit:

The data I am using is an unusual matrix with a lot of NAs. Perhaps this is the problem? But I would like to visualize these NAs in the heatmap as well. So only cluster rows but not the columns.

[dissimilar matrix example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEUq9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve this problem. I had to do simple imputation.
I just replaced all NAs with a "constant".

Then I can visualize the entire dataset without removing any samples or rows, cluster both rows and columns. Then, when I want to plot where the NAs are in the dataset, I just had to give the "constant" a specific colour in any plot.

In this way, I treat all the NAs the same without assigning NAs in each row/column a value based on other samples (such as mean/median/regression methods). This method works best for my dataset without skewing them in any direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting that error. The `dist` function should handle NAs by default. Below is an example. Also, you might want to simply compute your distance matrix first, and then feed to `hclust`. The `vegan` package can calculate many distance metrics, and you can specify if NAs should be removed:

```
# data
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 5)
df <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 5)

# make missing values
nvals <- length(c(df))
set.seed(1)
df[sample(x = nvals, size = nvals*0.1)] <- NaN

# distance "euclidean"
hc <- hclust(dist(df), method = "ave")
plot(hc)


# other distance metrics
D <- vegdist(df, method = "manhattan", na.rm = TRUE)
hc <- hclust(D, method = "ave")
plot(hc)
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. I see in your example, the data has only a few NAs which might help with clustering anyway. Please take a look at the example I added now to my question. The table has a lot of NAs for many rows. I do not want to delete them but wanna visualize them in the heatmap.

Comment: The issue is probably when you have zero values that match between any two samples - then you can not calculate a distance metric. You will likely have to filter out samples that contain too many NAs

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that solution when you remove them, it is possible to cluster. But, there should be a way to visualize them without filtering out any sample. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to manage the NA problem is to remove the column if the number of NA is superior to a threshold. The threshold will be the max the heatmap/cluster no longer works.

Such as
# remove columns if number of na is sup to  15
na_count <- colSums(is.na(t_Mat))
columns_to_remove <- which(na_count > 15)
# Remove identified columns
t_Mat <- t_Mat[, -columns_to_remove]